# Return all columns matching TRUE condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return all the records containing TRUE value in ANY of the of the two last column(User is Active and Customer is Active. If there is any TRUE in the record, no matter in which column, it should return the column as result. I am not getting desired results.

```
TRUE-TRUE = Must show the result.
TRUE-FALSE = Must show the result.
FALSE-TRUE = Must show the result.
TRUE-TRUE= Must show the result.
FALSE-FALSE = Must NOT return the result.
```

My code:

```
SELECT *
FROM t.Subscription
WHERE UserActive <> 'False' AND CustomerActive <> 'False';
```

```
ID  cID UserActive Customeractive
1   1   FALSE        FALSE
3   2   FALSE        TRUE
6   3   TRUE         TRUE
7   4   TRUE         FALSE
8   4   FALSE        FALSE
9   5   TRUE         TRUE
10  5   FALSE        TRUE
```

Comment: So you want to select rows where one column OR the other is true?

Comment: As Scott says, you want `OR` logic, not `AND` logic.

Comment: If you take a second to look at your query, you will clearly see that your condition is that both `UserActive` **AND** `CustomerActive` must be true... Therefore, you should simply use `OR` instead.

Comment: `AND` is not additive. This is a common confusion. You want `OR`.

Comment: Just say `= 'True' ` No reason to use the negation.

Comment: @shawnt00 I would agree, although as this is a text field, maybe he wants the field to be considered `true` if it is empty or has anything other than "False". Talking about suggestions, it should of course be a `bit` field.

Comment: It's a Boolean value. Not text. Hope this helps.

Comment: If it's a `bit` field, you can directly compare with `1` or `0`.

Comment: @user13231908 the question is whether our comments have helped you? Have you tried the suggestions yet?

Comment: Fair enough @Andrew, I guess you really never know with these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "True" in either column, don't you just want this?

```
WHERE UserActive = 'True' OR CustomerActive = 'TRUE';
```

Ironically, this is essentially equivalent to your version:

```
WHERE NOT (UserActive <> 'FALSE' AND CustomerActive <> 'FALSE')
```

*except* when the values could be `NULL`.  So, consider:

```
TRUE     NULL
```

The first version returns "true".  The second returns `NULL` -- and `WHERE` clauses treat `NULL`s as "false" (i.e. filters them out).

Comment: Your second line of code is exactly the same as what the user posted, maybe you wanted to have a `OR` instead? Or did you mean to use `WHERE NOT (UserActive = 'False' AND CustomerActive = 'False')`?

Comment: I don't understand which line of code is *"essentially equivalent to your version"*. I see one different (which fixes the issue) and one exactly equal.